# Please help me to explain this, idk what it means when these symbol combine together

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Review <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Review<T>> 
{

}
```

In particular I don't know what `<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Review<T>>` means

Comment: It means: `T` has to be a type which can be compared (to instances of the same type); and your Review type is a type which can be compared (to instances of the same type).

Comment: Did you try reading through the [tutorial in the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)?

Answer (score 1):

`Review <T extends Comparable<T>>` means that:

1. `Review` is a generic type.
2. `Review` has a type parameter `T`.
3. The type parameter `T` has the constraint that the actual type must extend the interface `Comparable<T>`.
4. If you look at the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) for `Comparable` you will see that this means that `T` will need to implement a `int compareTo(T)` method.

`implements Comparable<Review<T>>` means that:

1. `Review` implements `Comparable`
2. The signature of the `compareTo` method provided by `Review` must be `int compareTo(Review)`.

---

In summary, for an given elaboration of the review type (say) `Review<XYZ>` the `XYZ` type has to be comparable with another `XYZ`, and the `Review<XYZ>` type will then be comparable with another `Review<XYZ>`.